# jqPlot Pie chart data label does not show

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have such pie chart
which has data labels with values ["", 20, 1, 3, "", "", "", "", 4, 6, 6],
it shows all values without any problem, except that it doesn't show value 1.
How can i fix it or is it jqPlot bug?

[image]

My code is:

```
function getPieChart(res) {
    var data = [];
    $.each(res, function (ind, resData) {
        data.push([resData.Stage, resData.Count]);
    });
    var dataLbl = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i][1] != 0) {
            dataLbl.push(data[i][1]);
        }
        else {
            dataLbl.push('');
        }
    }
    var piePlot = jQuery.jqplot('pie-chart', [data],
      {
          seriesDefaults: {
              renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
              rendererOptions: {
                  showDataLabels: true,
                  dataLabels: dataLbl,
                  diameter: 250,
                  dataLabelPositionFactor: 0.5,
                  sliceMargin: 3,
                  color: '#DCDCDC'
              },
              shadow: false
          }
      }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i dont know whether you could solve this yet, but the problem is the dataLabelThreshold setting

by default its value is 3, so nothing below this value will be shown

try setting its value to zero (range is 0-100) like this

```
rendererOptions: { 
   dataLabelThreshold: 0, 
   showDataLabels: true, 
   dataLabels: labels, 
   dataLabelFormatString: "%s" 
}
```

Comment: you are right i solved it by making dataLabelThreshold equal 0

Answer (score 1):

By default labels will show the percentage, but if you set the `dataLabels` property to `label` the label passed in the data[] should be shown.  The code to put the labels into a new array is unnecessary.  See the third example in the documentation: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php

```
 var piePlot = jQuery.jqplot('pie-chart', [data],
  {
      seriesDefaults: {
          renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
          rendererOptions: {
              showDataLabels: true,
              dataLabels: 'label', //specify to use labels
              diameter: 250,
              dataLabelPositionFactor: 0.5,
              sliceMargin: 3,
              color: '#DCDCDC'
          },
          shadow: false
      }
  }
);
```

Also it appears you have already built an [[]] with `data`.  I do not think this should be further wrapped in an array.

```
var piePlot = jQuery.jqplot('pie-chart', data,
      {
        //ommitted
      }
```

Comment: i tried both dataLabels:'value' and dataLabels:'label', but still it does not show yellow slice value.

Comment: Did you try removing the array around data?  `var piePlot = jQuery.jqplot('pie-chart', [data],` to `var piePlot = jQuery.jqplot('pie-chart', data,`

Comment: If you log data to the console prior to calling jqGrid what do you receive?

Comment: data itself is two indexed array 
["new",0],["shortList",20],["interview",1],["Testing",3]....

Comment: @xurca Its something with the data, this simple test case works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/q7mtR/1/

Comment: okey just add more values to this array for example ["A",3] and so on: http://jsfiddle.net/uDBmj/ here interview with value 1 is missing...

Comment: @xurca Gotcha, I misunderstood your question.  Could you show the legend? It appears this is default functionality of jqPlot

Comment: never mind i found what i was doing wrong. i should add dataLabelThreshold=0 in rendererOptions.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already stated that you need to set the dataLabelThreshold to 0. I would like to add that you should also set the dataLabelPositionFactor to a value like 1.1 to make the value clearly visible.

```
rendererOptions: { 
   dataLabelThreshold: 0, 
   dataLabelPositionFactor: 1.1,
}
```

See related question. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448072/how-to-display-the-labels-outside-the-pie-chart-in-jqplot)