# How to display the labels outside the pie chart in jqplot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jqplot

Jqplot has the chart like following

[image]

[jqplot Chart](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php)

my question is how to display the labels outside a `jqplot chart` like the following `high chart`,

[image]

high chart is available at here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N3KAC/1/)

hight charts

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

How to achieve displaying labels outside the chart with lines in **jqplot**?

Comment: i dont understand your question? what is your need? the jsfiddle works as your image?

Comment: @Nouphal.M how to display the labels in jqplot outside of the chart? its my question.

Comment: like your second iamge?

Comment: @Nouphal.M yes like that

Comment: the jsfiddle that you provided already draws such a chart. Do you want to know how this is achieved?

Comment: @Nouphal.M that high chart, i would like to done it in jqplot

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dewRD/ dataLabelPositionFactor, i couldn't find any built in line drawing options. i think that you have to manually draw. Will inform if any progress

Comment: ok @Nouphal.M.. Pls let me know if you find anything

Answer (score 3):

*dataLabelPositionFactor* controls position of label on slice.  Increasing will slide label toward edge of pie, decreasing will slide label toward center of pie.

**dataLabelPositionFactor : 1.2,**

default *dataLabelThreshold*  value is 3,  hence values <=3 are not displayed hence make it to 0

**dataLabelThreshold : 0**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var data = [
    ['Heavy Industry', 12],['Retail', 9], ['Light Industry', 14], 
    ['Out of home', 16],['Commuting', 7], ['Orientation', 9]
  ];
  var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot ('chart1', [data], 
    { 
      seriesDefaults: {
        // Make this a pie chart.
        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer, 
        rendererOptions: {
          // Put data labels on the pie slices.
          // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
          showDataLabels: true, 
         //dataLabelPositionFactor controls position of label on slice.  Increasing will slide label toward edge of pie, decreasing will slide label toward center of pie.
         dataLabelPositionFactor : 1.2,
         // default dataLabelThreshold  value is 3,  hence values <=3 are not displayed hence make it to 0
         dataLabelThreshold : 0
        }
      }, 
      legend: { show:true, location: 'e' }
    }
  );
});
```

[image]

Comment: added image result of the pie after settings.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following settings to place the legend outside the pie chart and it worked for me:

```
legend: {show: true, location: 'ne',placement: 'outside'},
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're looking for is [this page.](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-pieRenderer-js.html#$.jqplot.PieRenderer.dataLabels)

Check out the info under the dataLabels subheading.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?